What is Gandharva vivah according to harita smriti?
Kindly explain the following verses which define gandharva marriage..
श्रुत्वा गन्धर्वमाश्रित्य विवाहं मन्त्रवित्पुमान्।
कन्यां ददौ महाभागां स्त्रीरत्नं विविधं व्रजेत्।।

गन्धर्वं विवाहं श्रेष्ठमाहुः शास्त्रविशारदाः।
स्वयं वरयते स्त्रीरत्नं यथाभीष्टं यथा मतिः।।

गन्धर्वः स्वयमेवाश्रित्य स्त्रीरत्नं विविधं व्रजेत्।
न भूयाः पार्थिवः पुत्रो न भूयाः पितृवित्तः स्वयम्।।

स्वयं वरयते नारीं यथाभीष्टं यथा मतिः।
न तद्वृत्तं पितुर्वित्तं स्यात्तस्मात्स्वयं वरयेत्।।

यद्यदिच्छेत्स्वयं नारी युवा युवेन संगमम्।
न तद्वृत्तं पितुर्वित्तं स्यात्तस्मात्स्वयं वरयेत्।।

स्त्री स्वयं वरयेद्युवतिं युवा युवेन संगमम्।
न तद्वृत्तं पितुर्वित्तं स्यात्तस्मात्स्वयं वरयेत्।।

यथा यथा स्वयं नारी वरयेद्युवमिष्टवत्।
तथा तथा सुतस्तस्याः स्यात्पितुर्न तु वित्तदः।।


Especially 10th shloka which says "nari varayed swayamishtavat".
What does varayed here mean does it mean "marries(undergoes marriage ritual" or just chooses a youth as husband and starts staying with him?
